# log into stubborn webpage via Python

Tags: python

I am not very experienced with this type of thing, but I cannot seem to log into this webpage via Python:  https://ravenpack.com/discovery/login/

I have tried solutions from other StackOverflow posts, but nothing seems to work.   It could be that it is not possible or I just do not know what I'm doing - either are likely possible

I have tried:

```
import requests

LOGIN_URL = 'https://ravenpack.com/discovery/login/'
DATA_URL = 'https://ravenpack.com/discovery/news_analytics_story/FFF4BFD4F4D4FF803852899BD1F02077/'

payload = {
    'username': 'uname',
    'password': 'pword'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    r = s.get(DATA_URL)
    print r.text
```

this:

```
from twill.commands import *
go('https://ravenpack.com/discovery/login/')



fv("2", "username", "uname")
fv("2", "password", "pword")

submit('1')
```

this:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("https://ravenpack.com/discovery/login/")      #Url that contains signin form
br.select_form()
br['username'] = "uname"    #see what is the name of txt input in form
br['password'] = 'pword'
result = br.submit().read()
f=file('s.html', 'w')
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

and this:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True,user_agent='Mozilla/5.0')
login_url = 'https://ravenpack.com/discovery/login/'
browser.open(login_url)
form = browser.get_form(id='login_form')
form['username'].value = 'uname' 
form['password'].value = 'pword'
browser.submit_form(form)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hard to help without valid username/pass but there is the `csrftoken` cookie that is also sent via the post param `csrfmiddlewaretoken`.

Comment: Also, if everything else fails, you may try selenium + phantomjs .

Comment: Thank you.  I will try to figure out the cookie and will try your other suggestion if I can't make any progress.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

LOGIN_URL = 'https://ravenpack.com/discovery/login/'
DATA_URL = 'https://ravenpack.com/discovery/news_analytics_story/FFF4BFD4F4D4FF803852899BD1F02077/'

username = 'user'
password = 'password'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(LOGIN_URL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
    r = s.get(DATA_URL)
    print r.text
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, but that does not appear to work - I know my inability to share login credentials makes this tough.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please explain your answers rather than dumping code

Comment: you simply use the `HTTPBasicAuth` param to declare a username and password assuming that it uses basic auth.